# Reg. the size of Android app in delphi

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7

When i'm generating android application through Delphi Xe7, the App_Name.Apk file 6 MB and when i'm installing in the mobile, the application size is 25 MB. Please provide me the information that there are any other settings to reduce the size of the application size. And in the code i'm having only single form, 6 class declaration. Also i'm using the Release settings which is in the Options (Shift+ctrl+F11).

Comment: What does "I'm using the debug option only" mean? The way to build small applications for android is to use the platform native tools.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409139/why-does-my-app-size-on-device-differ-than-the-apk-or-play-store-size

Comment: Sorry i'm using the release version. This settings will be in options.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Delphi XE7 is a cross platform development tool. The power is in it's cross platform nature. It provides a framework called Firemonkey that works on all four platforms (Android, IOS, OSX, Windows). The Firemonkey run time library weighs in at between 6MB and 10MB depending on the platform and the units you use. If you are using the graphical controls of Firemonkey you will have that size footprint.

Similar cross platform frameworks like Adobe AIR, QT, and others have a similar size footprint. However, you can add thousands of lines of code and hundreds of controls and the size will still be about the same.

It is possible to make a [bare bones Android app without using Firemonkey](http://www.fmxexpress.com/bare-bones-android-app-with-ndk-shared-object-built-in-delphi-xe7-without-firemonkey/) in either C++ or Object Pascal but you lose access to all of the Firemonkey controls.

Comment: Hi,
I think Delphi XE8 may be releasing next month and can we expect the reduction of size of the android application. Because this is the one small issue that we are facing. Other than that every thing is fine.

Comment: I doubt that is the case. Run time libraries usually increase in size with new versions as more functionality is added. I think Adobe AIR has increased in size for example.