# Size of delphi xe7 application on android

Tags: android, delphi, size

I'm using delphi xe7 for creating android program. My simple app with sql-lite base size 26 mb (in relize mode it's on google play *.apk file).

After installation on device with android version 4.2 in settings shows about 30 mb (not like java, but its alright)

But for android 4.1 - 4.0 the size becomes up to 63 and 103 megabytes and it is terrible :(. 
Are there any ways to make it more compact?

Comment: Do you compile in **Debug** or **Release** mode?

Comment: @SirRufo OP said Release but spelled it wrong.

Comment: Even when you compile for release, which you should, the executable will be humongous. If you want a small executable use the native tools.

Comment: I know at least when using VCL disabling RTTI drastically helps.

Comment: Reducing the application size is not possible and the good thing is the performance of the application is good. May be in future Delphi release, the Size of the application may reduce. And check the following link:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814660/reg-the-size-of-android-app-in-delphi