# Apk size increase after installation on device

Tags: android, memory-management, unity-game-engine, apk, android-proguard

My apk size is 20 MB and after installation on device, app size becomes 38 MB, out of which App is 37.10 MB and rest is other data. It will be great if anyone can explain the process of this conversation of data. Why after installation, data becomes so high and how I can decrease that.

I made apk using Unity and it is a game.

Comment: Check this answer: [Why does my app size on device differ than the APK or Play store size](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14488371/3572108)

Answer (score 2):

The apk file is compressed, and when you install the apk it decompressed the files. Usually it's the textures that are to blame for the biggest difference in size, so far as I know