# Difference in apk size while installing from appstore

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have my Android apk thats built locally. The apk size is 10.96MB. 
`ls -ltrh` reads as 11MB. I uploaded this apk to Google Play store and  tried installing the app from playstore, the progress bar reads as `1 MB/7.90 MB              10%`

Why question is why am I seeing 7.9MB instead of 10.96MB. Does Google play store optimize the apk?

Comment: See this http://android.stackexchange.com/q/107164/176147

Comment: @JaswanthManigundan, thanks for the link. My app does not have an OBB extension. Its just an 11MB app

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about google appstore but i am using another appstore that in  the information page said the apk size in appstore downloaded with 75% of real size and it is like compression.and `Jaswanth Manigundan's` comment is good too.

Answer (score 0):

i reserched this and i found that google will optimise and compress the app to save space on their servers and also make it faster to download. after downloading, the file will be *decompressed* and then installed, this saves *time and space*. also, google doesnt *optimise* the apk. it compresses it

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you share those links..much appreciated

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/107164/discrepancy-between-sizes-of-apps-listed-in-play-store-vs-actual-installed-app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409139/why-does-my-app-size-on-device-differ-than-the-apk-or-play-store-size

Comment: "i reserched this and i found that google will optimise and compress the app to save space on their servers and also make it faster to download. after downloading" I didnt find anything about these in those two links The links speak a different problem.

Comment: ok, fine. i lied. i didn't not research this. BUT, it does make sense why the size will be different. i just used my head to find the answer. isn't my answer very logical?

Comment: :) . Your answer makes sense. Even I feel the playstore may either be compressing the apk further using some proprietary algorithm than only play services can decompress it or I am missing something very basic