# Why is required space more than apk size when downloading from google play

Tags: android, apk

My apk size is 2.75MB. When I try to download it from Google Play I get a message saying that I need to free up 150MB of space. When I download the app, it is only 2.75MB. After downloading some content, it is still only about 7MB. Why is there such a discrepancy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409139/why-does-my-app-size-on-device-differ-than-the-apk-or-play-store-size

Answer (score 2):

The application is published in .apk form, which means all your source code along with the assets like images , music etc used in the app are in compressed form.

After installing, all the files gets decompressed, thus resulting in increase of the app size.

Some apps downloads extra files after you install them, and cache those files so that you can have a smoother experience with the app.

Android also provides various tools to compress the app before publishing it into the play store such as progaurd. Doing so, it is difficult to reverse engineer the app.

Viewing from the developer's perspective, the smaller the apk size, the more number of chances of it being downloaded. Therefore many developers use these tools to compress the application as much as possible resulting in smaller apk file size.

Thus although the size of the app in play store may seem less, after installing it may take a larger space in your phone.