# Minimum requirements to run an Android app

Tags: android

How to know the minimum device requirements to run my app in terms of memory and space. Is it through the minimum API which is 21 in my app or I need to monitor or calculate something. For space I build the APK with proguard true and it is 32,628kb while when I install it 50.79MB. Shall I say minimum space is 50.79MB?.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

it will be fine when you set requirement that this app requires API 21,and the size of your apk is important not your debug apk size, the specify size should be your released apk size.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no rocket science behind that. Check this thread: [Why does my app size on device differ than the APK or Play store size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409139/why-does-my-app-size-on-device-differ-than-the-apk-or-play-store-size)

Quoting from @PFROLIM:

> When installing an APK in android system, what's installed is the DEX
>   file. Which contains your code, resources etc compiled as binaries.
>   Your dex is generally the same size of your apk, unless you have
>   resources not compiled in assets.
>
> Well, we all know that. What's not widelly spread is that android
>   SAVES your original apk too. Perhaps for reinstalling in case of
>   errors or for some other reasons.
>
> **That's why the amount of memory of our apps is the double in system.
>   It's the sum of the size of the original apk and the installed dex.**