# What is the difference between 3 APKs generated from flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, apk, android-architecture-components

I need to understand the Android device architecture and, Why there is three different types of APKs are generated when I use:

`flutter build apk --split-per-abi`.

And when I use

`flutter build apk`

I get a large APK file called fat APK contains the 3 versions of the app.

Answer (score 6):

The command `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` typically generates two APK files.

1. `arm64` or x86_64 is the apk file for devices having 64-bit processors.
2. `x86` is the apk file for 32-bit processors.

You can upload both of them on the PlayStore and based on the user's device architecture the corresponding apk will be installed.

The fat apk that you are getting while using the `flutter build apk` contains the necessary compiled code to target all the Application Binary Interfaces or ABIs. Once a user downloads this fat apk, then only the code applicable to the device will be used.

Answer (score 2):

**`flutter build apk` gives you large apk because,**

> `flutter build apk` results in a fat APK that contains your code compiled for all the target ABIs. Such APKs are larger in size than their split counterparts, causing the user to download native binaries that are not applicable to their device’s architecture.

---

`--split-per-abi` results in two APK files:

> (The flutter build command defaults to --release.)

```
<app dir>/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk
<app dir>/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-arm64-v8a-release.apk
```

Where  armeabi-v7a for is 32-bit devices and arm64-v8a for 64-bit devices.

Read More on
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#build-an-apk
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#build-an-app-bundle
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-split

Comment: outputs>flutter-apk>app-release.apk and output>apk>release>app-release.apk are the same files ?

Comment: @TheNoobDeveloper0299, yes. Newer flutter versions use the "flutter-apk" path. The old path is kept for compatibility

Answer (score 1):

Run `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`

**This command results in three APK files:**

```
<app dir>/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk
<app dir>/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-arm64-v8a-release.apk
<app dir>/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-x86_64-release.apk
```

Removing the `--split-per-abi` flag results in a **fat APK** that contains your code compiled for **all the target ABIs** . Such APKs are larger in size than their split counterparts, causing the user to download native binaries that are not applicable to their device’s architecture.

> **ABI** means : Application Binary Interface
> **APK** means : Android Package
> **app dir** is your application’s directory

**NOTE :** If you can build an [**app bundle**](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#build-an-app-bundle) instead of [**apk**](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#build-an-apk) , **do it** .With this,  the [**application will be signed**](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#signing-the-app) more easily .
By default, the app bundle contains your Dart code and the Flutter runtime compiled for `armeabi-v7a (ARM 32-bit), arm64-v8a (ARM 64-bit), and x86-64 (x86 64-bit)`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that creating an App Bundle (an .aab file) is preferred over creating a fat APK or multiple APKs per abi. To assemble an App Bundle, run `flutter build appbundle`. The bundle will be created at `build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab`